# Tense: when they arrived VS when they had arrived

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs

Which of the following is grammatically correct and why?
1) He and his family had been weary *when they arrived the night before*, and they had observed but little of the place.

2) He and his family had been weary *when they had arrived the night before*, and they had observed but little of the place.

Answer (score 1):

They both seem grammatically correct.

The first one is the normal thing you would expect to hear or read.

The second seems to put a redundant, wordy emphasis on the finality and discreteness of the arrival. This is unnecessary because of the "had" previously in the sentence extends to the arrival as well.  This version has a slight clumsiness to it that you would not hear often in spoken English.